# Number of ternary sequences

Tags: combinatorics

How many $n$-digit ternary $(0, 1, 2)$ sequences with exactly nine $0s$ are there?

My attempt: Since we want exactly nine $0s$, there must be at least $9$ digits in the ternary sequence i.e. $n\geq9$.
For $n=9$, there can be only one such sequence (all $0s$).
For $n=10$, we choose $9$ out of $10$ and place $0s$. For the remaining one place, we have two choices. So, we get $C(10,9)\times2^{10-9}$
For $n=11$, we choose $9$ out of $11$ and place $0s$. For the remaining two places, we have two choices for each place.So, we get $C(11,9)\times2^{11-9}$
Hence, generalizing this, we get:
$$Number of Sequences=C(n,9)\times2^{n-9}$$
Please let me know if I am missing something. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks right to me.